# How to access list of dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas

```
dfarr = [df_0, df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4,]
```

df_0, df_1... are dataframes, dfarr is a list.

```
count = [0.14814814814814814, 0.0, 0.03571428571428571, 0.07692307692307693, 0.75]
threshold = 0.18 

for i in range(len[count]):
    if (threshold<count[i]):
        th = count.index(min(count)) - 1
        dfarr[th].append(dfarr[i])

    (i need to append data to df_1 (th=1) from df_4 i = 4)
```

Problem:so basically i need to append a particular row from a dataframe to next dataframe using threshold values. Each datframe has its threshold value which is stored in another array. so by comparing threshold have to append one row from dataframe with max threshold to min one

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: what trouble are you facing in `dfarr[index]` ?

Comment: after using dfarr[1], i will get to df_0(whole dataframe ). but i need to further access each row of df_0.

Comment: can you please edit your question as per your requirement?